# lbzip2 uncompress tar file

Tags: linux, zip, compression, tar

I compressed a folder with many subfolders ( about 50GB)

Compression:

```
tar -cjf test.tar.bz2 test
```

unzip:

```
lbzip2 -k -d -n 5 test.tar.bz2 ~/temp/
```

Why the output is a .tar file ?
I'm searching on google but I'm confused
I expect a uncompressed folder

Thank you

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/a/433409/336375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tar -xjf test.tar.bz2`

That will run `bunzip2` to decompress and it will extract the contents of the tar file.

If you feel the need to specifically use `lbzip2` for decompression, then:

`lbzip2 -dc < test.tar.bz2 | tar xf -`

Comment: I'm sorry , what '-' character here means ?

Comment: Read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

These might help:

```sh
# Compress a folder with many subfolders and files.
function compress() {
    # Get the name of the folder to compress.
    echo "Enter the name of the folder to compress:"
    read folder
    # Get the name of the compressed file.
    echo "Enter the name of the compressed file:"
    read file
    # Compress the folder.
    tar -czf $file $folder
}

# Decompress a tar file into a folder using lbzip2.
function decompress() {
    # Get the name of the file to decompress.
    echo "Enter the name of the file to decompress:"
    read file
    # Get the name of the folder to decompress into.
    echo "Enter the name of the folder to decompress into:"
    read folder
    # Decompress the file.
    lbzip2 -d $file
    # Extract the file.
    tar -xzf $file -C $folder
}
```

Comment: I suspect he wants to use `lbzip2` for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank PCDSandwichMan but I have to use lbzip2

Comment: @JohnW Just for decompression? So would that update work?

Comment: oh ok . but Why do you use tar -xzf isn't slow ? peraphs I confused decompression with "extraction"..

Comment: Tar for decompression is a killer for sure but extraction is just IO